# Adding new columns with amount in percentage depending on states to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

This is my DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2020-08-20','2020-08-20','2020-08-20','2020-08-20','2020-08-20','2020-08-20'], 'Product' : ['A','B','C','A','B','C'], 'Amount' : [500,500, 700, 500,200,300], 'Status' : [1,1,1,0,0,0]})
```

My goal is to get the amount in percentage per product per state for the day. So when I use

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Amount', index=['Date', 'Status'],
                columns=['Product'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

I get a Dataframe like this:

[image]

How can I add three new columns so that for each product the percentual share per status is calculated? Thus, the new column ['A with 0'] should be 0.5 , for [B' with 0'] 0.29 and for ['C with 0'] 0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with new `DataFrame` created by divided aggregates with `sum` values with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for avoid duplicated columns names:

```
df1 = df1.join(df1.div(df1.groupby(level=0).sum(), level=0).add_prefix('pct_'))

#alternative
#df1 = df1.join(df1.div(df1.sum(level=0), level=0).add_prefix('pct_'))
print (df1)
Product              A    B    C  pct_A     pct_B  pct_C
Date       Status                                       
2020-08-20 0       500  200  300    0.5  0.285714    0.3
           1       500  500  700    0.5  0.714286    0.7
```

EDIT: For select by `Status=0` use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) by second level:

```
print (df1.xs(0, axis=0, level=1))
Product       A    B    C  pct_A     pct_B  pct_C
Date                                             
2020-08-20  500  200  300    0.5  0.285714    0.3
```

Comment: Ok. Would it be possible to only show status 0 for each date?

Comment: Your solution works for me with just one date. In my dataframe I have many dates though. So what I need is the amount in percentage for each day. When I enter your code it calculates the amounts per product for all days. Sorry forgot this in my code.